# Create a card from a list in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards

There is an option to convert any particular task list item into a card. Is there any option to convert a whole list into a card?

Sometimes we add multiple checklists in the same card and later on we need to move a completed checklist to card.

Answer (score 3):

With the copy card functionality you could select 'Copy' from the card menu and check to only keep the checklist items.

You can then open the copied card, select the drop down menu on any checklists you do not want, and select delete.

A little tedious but it gets the job done :)

Comment: I did the same way.. But there should be an direct option for this.